# View holder pattern for dynamically created ListView items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I know that when you are using a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter` and a layout resource, you should use the view holder pattern to reuse the `convertView` in order to improve the smoothness of scrolling for example.

What about if the items of a `ListView` are generated dynamically, using for example `new RelativeLayout(context)` and adding the contents using `addView()`? In this situation should I use something similar to the view holder pattern to reuse the `RelativeLayout`? By this I mean something along the lines of this.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.getTag();
relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
// Now add all the required Views.
```

Is using a view holder pattern to avoid instantiating a new instance of `RelatativeLayout` justified or is the primary reason for using the view holder pattern to avoid all the calls to `findViewById` from an inflated resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @ivan-bartsov and will add that both operations, namely, inflation and finding views by ids, are expensive and the reason why a ViewHolder pattern is the way to go.

I also wanted to mention this. If you have a finite number of view combinations, lets say 1, 2, 3, or even 4, then it will be a very good idea to override `Adapter.getViewTypeCount` and `Adapter.getItemViewType` so you can take advantage of the built in ViewHolder/Recycling capabilities for different item layouts. The framework will properly hand you the proper convertView for a given position.

On a final note, sometimes the data will be structured in a way that it will make more sense to use an ExpandableListView or a similar widget that will provide out of the box view recycling for child views, so you don't have to inflate them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely should still use `ViewHolder`. The manual view creation scenario is not that much different from when you inflate.

> Is using a view holder pattern to avoid instantiating a new instance
>   of RelatativeLayout justified or is the primary reason for using the
>   view holder pattern to avoid all the calls to `findViewById` from an
>   inflated resource?

Actually, you avoid redundant instantiation of `RelativeLayout` (or whatever) by checking the `convertView` parameter of `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` for `null`, you should do the same when you create the view manually.

You still need a way to access your subviews (`TextView`s or what have you), so you'll either use manually-made-up ids or tags to search by or use `ViewHolder` to store object references (which is, of course, faster)